# How do I find the index of a 2d meshgrid that corresponds to a given coordinate?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

So, I'm having trouble trying to search for the location of a cordinate on a meshgrid (two 2d arrays). A simple example looks like:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]  
    y = [4,5,6]
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    coord = [1,5] #the coordinate I am looking for

    print(xx)
    print(yy)

[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]

[[4 4 4]
 [5 5 5]
 [6 6 6]]
```

I would like the code to return `coord_idx = [1,0]`, the index where the coordinate is stored, such that `[xx[coord_idx],yy[coord_idx]]` returns `[1,5]`.

Comment: `np.argwhere((xx==coord[0]) & (yy==coord[1]))+1`? Or you are looking to avoid creating the meshes altogether?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - Find spatial position of a gridpoint in 3-d matrix (knowing the index of that gridpoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820734/numpy-find-spatial-position-of-a-gridpoint-in-3-d-matrix-knowing-the-index-of)

Comment: `xx[[2,1]]` is `2` and `yy[[2,1]]` is `6`. How do you expect to get `1` and `5`?

Comment: Divakar gave exactly what I needed- thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

coord = [1,5]

coord_idx = np.argwhere((xx==coord[0]) & (yy==coord[1]))[0]
```

Comment: Okay, then you can use @Divakar's answer. I'll add it to mine